# Does jQuery dialog display as hidden by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery dialog in a simple, typical use case:

In the Javascript:

```
$('myDialog').dialog({
    modal: true;
});
```

In HTML:

```
<div id="myDialog" title="Dialog Title">
    Dialog contents here
</div>
```

However, the CSS I'm using to control the layout & look-and-feel of the `myDialog` div is hosted on a server that my local machine doesn't have access to (don't ask why). Ergo, in Firebug, I see a network 404 error of file not found for the CSS file.

When I test this dialog out locally, it displays perfectly fine. However I just noticed that the contents of the `myDialog` div are actually displayed on my HTML page *prior* to when the code that executes the dialog's invocation is triggered.

So, this leads me to believe one of two things:

- A jQuery dialog's respective `<div>` element is invisible/hidden by default; however this weird situation where the browser can't find the CSS file is causing the `<div>` to display to the user before the dialog even pops up on screen; or
- A jQuery dialog's respective `<div>` element is visible by default, and that I must take action to hide it on page load

**Can someone please tell me which of those two assertions are correct?**

If the former assertion is correct, then the problem *should* resolve itself when we push the code to our dev environment (which *does* have access to the CSS file).

If the latter assertion is correct, then how can I hide the `myDialog` div on page load?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The second is more or less correct. When the page loads the `<div>` is visible because by default all `<div>`s in HTML are visible. jQuery only comes along for the ride later.

You should simply make the `<div>` hidden by default, and let `.dialog` decide when to show it, for example:

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDialog" class="hidden" title="Dialog Title">
    Dialog contents here
</div>
```

If you don't do this then things would deteriorate from "undesirable" to "unacceptable" if the dialog was not supposed to open immediately on page load. [**See an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/FDQzN/).

Comment: that does not work :) the dialogs stay hidden

Answer (score 1):

You can set the autoOpen option to be false.

```
$('foo').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'I\'m hidden',
    width: 500,
    height: 500
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second assertion is right. Calling `.dialog()` on a div, shows the dialog immediately